# MORYX application crashes on start

Tags: c#, moryx

After cloning [the template](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Template) and debugging the solution, the application opens for a split second, an error message is displayed briefly and it closes again.

How can you find out what happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of an [unhandled domain exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netcore-3.1) .NET applications are closed. Before that happens MORYX prints the exception to the console **and** writes a crash log under */ExecutionDirectory/CrashLogs/CrashLog_xx.txt*. To view the console message, run the application outside the debugger with `dotnet run xxx`.

In this particular case, the best guess is that the configured HTTP port can not be opened, due to missing rights or because it is already used.